# Phonegap Push Notification - PushNotification.init() not firing

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

I have a Phonegap project which is attempting to receive push notifications using the **phonegap-plugin-push**.

I have signed up and setup my Firebase app (FCM) and downloaded the **google-services.json** and placed it in my root (next to the config.xml).

When I test using Phonegap Mobile Dev App on my device, the PushNotification.init() is firing as expected.

** **Problem:** When I compile and install an APK through Phonegap Build (online), the PushNotification.init() is not firing.

My config.xml looks like this:

```
<engine name="android" spec="^7.0.0" />
<engine name="browser" spec="^5.0.4" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^2.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="^6.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" spec="^1.11.0" />
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="^2.1.3">
    <variable name="FCM_VERSION" value="11.6.2" />
</plugin>
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />
</platform>
```

My index.js looks like this:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    console.log('DEVICE READY...');

    var push = PushNotification.init({
        "android": {
            vibrate: true,
            sound: true,
            forceShow: true,
        },
        "browser": {
            pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
        },
        "ios": {
            alert: true,
            badge: true,
            sound: true
        }
    });

    push.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("push error = " + e.message);
    });

    push.subscribe('example', function () {
        console.log('Subscription error:');
        console.log(e);
    });

    PushNotification.hasPermission(function (data) {
        console.log("data.isEnabled = " + data.isEnabled);
    });


    push.on('registration', function (data) {
        console.log(data.registrationId);
        console.log(data.registrationType);
    });

    push.on('notification', function (data) {
        console.log(data.message);
        console.log(data.title);
        console.log(data.count);
        console.log(data.sound);
        console.log(data.image);
        console.log(data.additionalData);
        console.log(navigator.notification);

        navigator.notification.alert(data.message, null, data.title,'Ok');
    });
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I wen't thru many issues when trying to get push notifications up and running.
Not exactly the solution you asked for - but so far `cordova-plugin-firebase` is the only plugin I got working reliably.

PS.
If I remember correctly there is a small mistake in their iOS setup guide.

> Click the expand arrow to the left of the certificate’s name to reveal
>   the private key option

This part is incorrect, you need to export entire certificate without expanding.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I can't believe how terribly documented and implemented some of these features are. Anyway, I solved my issue. Answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I managed to achieve basic Push Notification functionality (only tested on Android so far) by completely starting a new project and using this code from [github](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push).

After this, I installed pieces of my previous codebase, along with their respective plugins on top of this, without breaking anything. So far so good.